# JS code transform into a string

Tags: javascript, string, transform

How can I transform all the following code into a string?

```
document.body.innerHTML = 'some text with "special" symbols like ' + " ' " + ' and like \' &#38; \'';
```

Comment: what do u mean? what "All" ?

Comment: Where is the code to being with? Do you obtain it via AJAX? Do you read it from a file?

Comment: the whole line -- from `document` to `;`

Comment: reading it -- not from ajax

Comment: write string as you do and escape all symbols by using  ` \ `

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the string as a var:

```
var myString = 'Some text with "special" symbols like ';
myString += '" " and like';
myString += " \' &#38; \'";

document.body.innerHTML = myString;
```

Comment: the string must include `document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: Then is:
var myString = 'document.body.innerHTML = Some text with "special" symbols like ';
myString += '" " and like';
myString += " \' &#38; \'";

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = "document.body.innerHTML = 'some text with \"special\" symbols like ' + \" ' \" + ' and like \' &#38; \'';";
```

just escape the inner " in the assignment with \"

Comment: ok, just how should I replace all `"` with `\"` ? -- it cannot be manually

Comment: where to do want to put the string? then i can explain